# Camel Sftp - Download Multiple Files

Tags: apache-camel

I am able to successfully download one/all files from  a sftp directory using the following uri in canmel route definition

Download all files

```
"sftp://userName@serverName/directoryName?knownHostsFile=./known_hosts&privateKeyFile=./id_rsa&proxy=#proxy&noop=true"
```

Download one file

```
"sftp://userName@serverName/directoryName?knownHostsFile=./known_hosts&privateKeyFile=./id_rsa&proxy=#proxy&noop=true&fileName=one.txt"
```

My requirement is to download a specific list of files = one.text, two.text.

How can I pass list of fileNames to the Camel route? Preferablly I am looking for a solution where in I can specify something like the below

```
"sftp://userName@serverName/directoryName?knownHostsFile=./known_hosts&privateKeyFile=./id_rsa&proxy=#proxy&noop=true&fileName=one.txt,two.txt"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Camel FTP component extends the File component and many of the options from file is also applicable for the FTP component, so read this page

- http://camel.apache.org/file2

You can for example use include to specify a regular expression that matches the files you want. Or implement a custom filter class and use the filter option, etc.